# Python list-dictionary algorithm with big data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, python-3.6

I'm trying to make a program using two python dictionaries.
'multiple dic1 and dic2 value if dic1 and dic2 key is common, otherwize 0'
the key order and the length of the output list is the same as those of dic1.

```
dic1 = {'foo': 100,'bar': 200,'baz': 300,'qux': 400,'quux': 500}
dic2 = {'foo': 1,'quux': 2}

# output [100, 0, 0, 0, 1000]
```

Of course I can do it with the code below.

```
output = []
for k,v in dic1.items():
    if k in dic2:
        output.append(v*dic2[k])
    else:
        output.append(0)
print(output)
```

but the length of the dictionary is 1K-10K so I cannot use for loop because of the speed problem.
Can someone know the way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "key order"? In Python, dictionaries are not deemed to be ordered. It may work in Python 3.6+, but this is an implementation detail which should not be relied upon.

Comment: @jpp In python 3.7 they are ;) https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Comment: @FHTMitchell, yep I'm well aware of Guido's ruling. But OP should make this explicit. Not everyone is using 3.7. In fact, I'd say only a small minority do.

Comment: I forgot to write. Python ver. is 3.6.

Comment: Why is this tagged `numpy` and `scipy` instead of `python3.x`?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I don't think there is much you can do. Where is this data coming from? If it's a csv or something then a `pandas` solution would probably be quicker. If they must be `dict`s then I think the best thing I can think of is to change it to a comprehension

```
output = [v * dic2[k] if k in dic2 else 0 for k, v in dic1.items()]
```

which removes the relatively expensive `list.append` call.

Some timings:

```
import numpy as np  # for random generation
dic1 = {k: k for k in np.random.random(10000)}
dic2 = {k: k for k in np.random.choice(list(dic1), 1000)}

def f1():
    output = []
    for k, v in dic1.items():
        if k in dic2:
            output.append(v*dic2[k])
        else:
            output.append(0)

def f2():
    output = [v * dic2[k] if k in dic2 else 0 for k, v in dic1.items()]

def f3():
    output = [v * dic2.get(k, 0) for k, v in dic1.items()]

%timeit f1()
2.44 ms ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit f2()
1.66 ms ± 14.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit f3()
2.61 ms ± 59.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each
```

Comment: Added **[ +1 ]** for a will to execute and present the few quantitative details on benchmarking approaches at least in the [TIME]-domain, **yet would be fair to challenge the [SPACE]-domain either** and pay more care to rigorously demonstrate the **scaling issues** -- going to sizes somewhere well above 1E+3 --> 1E+6 --> 1E+9 ( scaling matters, ... a lot ...  ) **Didn't o/p mention the Big Data....?** A remark on 10k is not an excuse for not doing this **:o)**

Comment: @user3666197 you're right, but in my defence the OP said that the size was 1-10k and that his trouble was in the time domain. But for a more general solution, obviously other considerations must be considered.

Comment: **Looking forward to see the extended landscapes of performance comparisons**. You have also mentioned `pandas`, haven't you? **One would start to see indeed Things "There", going further above 1E+9 ...**

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [v * dic2.get(k, 0) for k, v in dic1.items()]
```

It's not a loop ... it's a list comprehension and rather than checking for key existence in `dic2` and then choosing the value ... a handy call to `get` sorts out the problem of which value is part of the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

why not use pandas here? this solution will do away with the iterations. so:

1) convert the dictionaries into pandas DataFrame object

```
one = pd.DataFrame({'foo': 100,'bar': 200,'baz': 300,'qux': 400,'quux': 500}, index=range(1)).T
two = pd.DataFrame({'foo': 1,'quux': 2},index=range(1)).T
```

2) concat both the dataframes

```
pd.concat([one*two], axis=1)
```

3) if you wish to convert the dataframe object back to dictionary, than

```
pd.concat([one*two], axis=1).to_dict().get(0)
```

note: pandas concat operations will sort the dictionary keys. If you want to preserve orginial order, maybe you should first sort the raw input (the dictionary by keys) before converting it into pandas dataframe object.